# Some inequality problem, which is larger?

Tags: inequality

There is a set of n random numbers whose sum equals 1, i.e., $$w_a=\{w_{a1},\; w_{a2},\; \ldots,\; w_{an}\}$$ where $$ w_{a1} + w_{a2}+ \ldots+ w_{an} =1$$ and $$0 < \{ w_{a1}, w_{a2}, \ldots, w_{an} \}< 1.$$
There is another set of n random numbers whose sum also equals 1, i.e., $$w_b=\{w_{b1},\; w_{b2},\; \ldots,\; w_{bn}\}$$ where $$ w_{b1} + w_{b2}+ \ldots+ w_{bn} =1$$ and $$0 < \{ w_{b1}, w_{b2}, \ldots, w_{bn} \}< 1.$$
Then, we define (product of two elements): $$w_p = [w_{a1}\cdot w_{b1},\; w_{a2}\cdot w_{b2},\; ..., \; w_{an}\cdot w_{bn}].$$ 
$$w_{p1} = w_{p}(1), w_{p2} = w_{p}(2), ...,w_{pn}=w_{p}(n).$$ $$w_1 = \frac{w_{p1}}{\sum(w_p)}, w_2 = \frac{w_{p2}}{\sum(w_p)},...,w_n=\frac{w_{pn}}{\sum(w_p)}.$$ 
$$w = [w_1,\; w_2 ,\; ... ,\; w_n]$$ and $$w_1+w_2+\ldots+w_n = 1.$$ 
We define additionally (minimum of two elements), 
$$w_{p_{mm}} = [min(w_{a1},w_{b1}),\; min(w_{a2},w_{b2}),\; \ldots ,\; min(w_{an},w_{bn})].$$ 
$$w_{p1_{mm}} = w_{p_{mm}}(1), w_{p2_{mm}} = w_{p_{mm}}(2), \ldots, w_{pn_{mm}}=w_{p_{mm}}(n).$$ 
$$w_{1_{mm}} = \frac{w_{p1_{mm}}}{\sum(w_{p_{mm}})}, w_{2_{mm}} = \frac{w_{p2_{mm}}}{\sum(w_{p_{mm}})}, \ldots, w_{n_{mm}}=\frac{w_{pn_{mm}}}{\sum(w_{p_{mm}})}.$$ 
$$w_{mm} = [w_{1_{mm}},\;  w_{2_{mm}}, \ldots ,\;w_{n_{mm}}]$$ and $$w_{1_{mm}}+w_{2_{mm}}+\ldots+w_{n_{mm}} = 1.$$
When above is satisfied, I would like to prove: $$Var(w) \geqq Var(w_{mm}),$$ where it is the population variance, but not sample variance. I confirmed it by simulations, but I would like to prove it analytically.

Comment: As is, this is unreadable; please use mathjax (https://www.mathjax.org) to format it!

Comment: This question would be clearer if you could show a small example.  For instance, could you show us these two variances for the case $w_a=(1/6,1/3,1/2)$ and $w_b=(6/11,3/11,2/11)$?  I obtain $w=(1/3,1/3,1/3)$ and understand its "population variance" to be *zero,* whereas $w_{mm}=(11/41,18/41,12/41)$ has a positive population variance. Since zero obviously does not exceed the latter, at what juncture did I err in my interpretation?

Comment: whuber: I think you found a counter example. But in my simulations, usually n>100, for the same index in two sets, we may assume that the elements follow the same probability density function with very small variance. So, the magnitude of elements may not be big different like in the case of first one, (1/6, 6/11) and the third one (1/2, 2/11).  Then, the problem will be very complex?

Comment: whuber: So,  as an example, wa=( 0.1667    0.3333    0.5000
) and wb=(0.1791    0.2388    0.5821) would be very possible example.